# what is the pinescript security function 3rd argment

Tags: pine-script

I cant understand about security function 3rd argument

```
nAMA = nz(nAMA[1])  + nsmooth * (xPrice - nz(nAMA[1]))
ha_t = heikinashi(tickerid)
ha_close = security(ha_t, period, nAMA)
```

How should I interpret this syntax? ( nAMA )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd argument is the expression. Basically the data you want to get from the security call. In your case, it will be `nAMA`'s value in heikinashi bars.

If you are asking about how `nAMA` is calculated, it is simple maths actually.

The [nz()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v3/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#preventing-na-values-functions-na-and-nz) function takes an argument and if it is equal to `na` then it returns 0, otherwise it returns the argument’s value. Usually used when you want to refer to historical data. When you do that, the very first bar will return `na` for historical values because it is the first bar and there is no history yet.

Once you understand how `nz()` works, you can think that expression like `nAMA = nAMA[1]  + nsmooth * (xPrice - nAMA[1])` where `nAMA[1]` is `nAMA`'s previous value.